# add a "+" button in a navigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I try to add a "add button" in the navigationBar, but the button who is created is a rectangle button with no text inside, not a "+" button, why?

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(ajouterItem)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

[addButton release];
```

Comment: sounds weird, can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing up the initializer with the one for title/style. You want this form:

`- (id)initWithBarButtonSystemItem:(UIBarButtonSystemItem)systemItem target:(id)target action:(SEL)action`

Call it like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(ajouterItem)];
```